# There is no device with ID Using Zend and WURFL

Tags: zend-framework, wurfl

I have integrate WURFL 1.6.0 with Zend every thing goes smooth it detects the desktop but in case of Android i am getting this error .On digging in deep i found out that my dir data/wurfl/cache is not loading with any data i have given it 777 permission but still it didnt work.

```
[25-Jun-2015 09:39:09] PHP Fatal error: 
 Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'There is no device with ID [generic_android_ver4_4] in the loaded WURFL Data' in /var/www/vhosts/mobiletocash.co.uk/httpdocs/library/wurfl-php-1.6.0.1/WURFL/CustomDeviceRepository.php:108
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/mobiletocash.co.uk/httpdocs/library/wurfl-php-1.6.0.1/WURFL/CustomDeviceRepository.php(211): WURFL_CustomDeviceRepository->getDevice('generic_android...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mobiletocash.co.uk/httpdocs/library/wurfl-php-1.6.0.1/WURFL/WURFLService.php(146): WURFL_CustomDeviceRepository->getDeviceHierarchy('generic_android...')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mobiletocash.co.uk/httpdocs/library/wurfl-php-1.6.0.1/WURFL/WURFLService.php(62): WURFL_WURFLService->getWrappedDevice('generic_android...', Object(WURFL_Request_GenericRequest))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mobiletocash.co.uk/httpdocs/library/wurfl-php-1.6.0.1/WURFL/WURFLManager.php(90): WURFL_WURFLService->getDeviceForRequest(Object(WURFL_Request_GenericRequest))
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mobiletocash.co.uk/httpdocs/library in /var/www/vhosts/mobiletocash.co.uk/httpdocs/library/wurfl-php-1.6.0.1/WURFL/CustomDeviceRepository.php on line 108

$resourcesDir            = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../data/wurfl/';

$wurfl['main-file']      = $resourcesDir  . 'wurfl.xml';
$wurfl['patches']        = array($resourcesDir . 'web_browsers_patch.xml');

$cache['provider']       = 'Null';
//
$persistence['provider'] = 'File';
$persistence['dir']      = $resourcesDir . '/cache/';


$configuration['wurfl']       = $wurfl;
$configuration['persistence'] = $persistence; 
$configuration['cache']       = $cache;
```

if i give     $cache['provider']       = null;
it throws another exception . tried using   $persistence['provider'] = 'file';  but no use

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell it does not look like the WURFL file is being properly loaded (perhaps the directory is not writeable) or is out of date.  You most likely need to delete the persistence directory and reload the WURFL API.

Comment: already tried that ... chmod 777 , delete dir etc nothing works but the issue is the directory rights etc